# Swift 3.0 Converting String to Double returning nil?

Tags: json, string, null, swift3, double

Trying to do something so simple but it's simply not working for me.

CODE:

```
let long = index["Longitude"] as! String
let lat = index["Latitude"] as! String

print(long as Any)
print(lat as Any)

let doubleLong = Double(long)
print(doubleLong as Any)
```

DEBUG OUTPUT:

```
-85.1113644443208 
32.880541654362 
nil
```

^^^ Why so nil? I will add this is being pulled from a JSON Response. Perhaps this has something to do with it.

Comment: What is `lancerLong`?

Comment: @RemyCilia Just fixed it above. typed in the wrong variable..

Comment: Show the excerpt of the JSON. By the way, what are those `as Any` casts for? And conform to the naming convention that variable names start always with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @vadian I am assumming the casts are there to silence the warning "Expression implicitly coerced to Any".

Comment: @Sulthan But the first two results are clearly non-optional `String`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely there is an additional space in your data, note:

```
print(Double("-85.1113644443208")) // => Optional(-85.111364444320799)
print(Double("-85.1113644443208 ")) // => nil
print(Double(" -85.1113644443208")) // => nil
```

Try to trim the spaces first:

```
let doubleLong = Double(long.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces))
```

or use a `NumberFormatter` for parsing:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

print(numberFormatter.number(from: "-85.1113644443208") as Double?) // => Optional(-85.111364444320799)
print(numberFormatter.number(from: " -85.1113644443208") as Double?) // => Optional(-85.111364444320799)
print(numberFormatter.number(from: "-85.1113644443208 ") as Double?) // => Optional(-85.111364444320799)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are new failable initializers that allow you to do this in more idiomatic and safe way (as many answers have noted, String's double value is not very safe because it returns 0 for non number values. This means that the doubleValue of "foo" and "0" are the same.)

let myDouble = Double(myString)

This returns an optional, so in cases like passing in "foo" where doubleValue would have returned 0, the failable intializer will return nil. You can use a guard, if-let, or map to handle the Optional